# "For loop" in newcommand

Tags: macros, loops

I have this command

```
\newcommand{\pdfappendix}[1]{
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{pdf/#1.pdf}
}
```

It works well when I have 1 page pdf but is not including the other pages. Now I decided to change the command to take a second argument which is the number of pages and will repeat `\includegraphics` that number of times.

I want something similar to (the following is not latex code):

```
\newcommand{\pdfappendix}[2]{
    for index=1 to #2
    {
       \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{pdf/#1index.pdf}
    }
}
```

Example: MyPDF.pdf has 4 pages. I will split it in 4 pdfs with 1 page each: MyPDF1.pdf, MyPDF2.pdf, MyPDF3.pdf, MyPDF4.pdf. The output of the command will be:

Then I will write the command: \pdfappendix{MyPDF}{4}

And it will output:

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{pdf/MyPDF1.pdf}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{pdf/MyPDF2.pdf}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{pdf/MyPDF3.pdf}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{pdf/MyPDF4.pdf}
```

Is it possible to do that?

PS: I don't want to use `\includepdf` because I have some problems with section headers.

Comment: What about `\includegraphics[scale=0.6,page=2]{...}`? I've heard that you can select the page directly in the options. Not 100% sure about this.

Comment: @topskip, I use exactly this method and it works.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\def\pdfappendix#1#2{%
  \foreach \index in {1, ..., #2} {%
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{#1\index.pdf}\par%
  }}

\begin{document}
  \pdfappendix{pdf/test}{4}
\end{document}
```

The above code will the thing you want. However I haven't tested it extensively. I just tested this minimal example and it works.

Comment: Is there any way to see (e.g. for copy/paste purposes) the generated latex code?

Answer (score 21):

For the sake of completeness, in Luatex:

```
\newcommand{\pdfappendix}[2]{
    \directlua{
        for index=1,#2 do 
            tex.print("\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{pdf/#1"..index..".pdf}")
        end}
```

Answer (score 17):

A solution without any extra packages

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% introduce a dummy counter, initially 0    
\newcount\tmp

\newcommand{\pdfappendix}[2]{% need this to prevent extra vertical space
    % #1: image path and core part of name
    % #2: maximum number
    \tmp=0
    \loop
        % increment dummy counter
        \advance\tmp by 1
        % include the image
        \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{#1\number\tmp.pdf}
        % repeat the loop provided the counter is within specified bound
        \ifnum\tmp<#2
    \repeat
}

\begin{document}

\pdfappendix{pdf/test}{5}

\newpage
\pdfappendix{pdf/test}{3}

\newpage
\pdfappendix{pdf/test}{2}

\newpage
\pdfappendix{pdf/test}{1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To avoid the loop, you can try to call your command recursively until `#1` equals `#2`...

Comment: Good! You can use `\aftergroup` to avoid too deep recursion... ;-)

Comment: @PaulGaborit I'll do some reading- haven't used `\aftergroup` before- thanks for the idea :)

Comment: The second solution doesn't resolve tail recursion and `\includegraphics` is heavy enough to consume resources. "Recursive macros tend to clutter up TEX’s memory if too many *incarnations* of such a macro are active at the same time. However, TEX is able to prevent this in one frequently occurring case of recursion: tail recursion." - TeX by Topic

Comment: @AhmedMusa thanks for pointing that out... another problem with the recursive definition was that it wouldn't work as expected if called more than once in a document- have deleted

Answer (score 15):

```
\usepackage{multido}
\newcommand\pdfappendix[2]{%
  \multido{\I=1+1}{#2}{%
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{pdf/#1\I.pdf}}}
```

Comment: There are quite a lot of choices. (La)TeX's `\loop \repeat`, `forloop`'s `\forLoop`, `ifthen`'s `\whiledo`, `etoolbox`'s `\whileboolexpr`, `expl3`'s `\prg_stepwise_function`, and `pgffor` and `multido`.

Answer (score 8):

Just to do it differently, by recursion:

```
\newcommand\pdfappendix[2]{%
  %% initialize the "container" macro
  \def\pdfappendixcommand{}
  %% store the common prefix
  \def\pdfappendixcommon{#1}%
  %% start the recursion
  \dopdfappendix{1}{#2}}
\newcommand\dopdfappendix[2]{%
  \ifnum#1>#2
    %% terminate the recursion
    \expandafter\pdfappendixcommand
  \else
    %% append to \pdfappendixcommand
    \edef\pdfappendixcommand{%
      \unexpanded\expandafter{\pdfappendixcommand}\space
      \noexpand\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{\pdfappendixcommon#1.pdf}}%
    %% call \dopdfappendix{#1+1}{#2} (but computing "#1+1" and expanding \fi)
    \expandafter\dopdfappendix\expandafter
      {\number\numexpr#1+1\expandafter}% First argument to \dopdfappendix
      \expandafter{\number#2\expandafter}% Second argument to \dopdfappendix
  \fi}
```

Then

```
\pdfappendix{pdf/MyPDF}{5}
```

will do the required thing. The trick is to build recursively a macro that will contain all the instructions. For instance, `\pdfappendix{pdf/MyPDF}{2}` will build `\pdfappendixcommand` expanding to

```
 \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{pdf/MyPDF1.pdf} \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{pdf/MyPDF2.pdf}
```

All the `\ifnum` are evaluated at nesting level 1, because the call to `\dopdfappendix` is made after the `\fi` has been expanded.

What happens is that the following commands are called in turn (second argument 5):

```
\dopdfappendix{1}{5}
\dopdfappendix{2}{5}
\dopdfappendix{3}{5}
\dopdfappendix{4}{5}
\dopdfappendix{5}{5}
\dopdfappendix{6}{5}
```

and the last one will execute

```
\pdfappendixcommand
```

instead of continuing the recursion.

Comment: +1 so this resolves the tail recursion that @Ahmed mentioned in his comment to my answer (which my attempt didn't manage)

Comment: @cmhughes I added it just because you removed your attempt. Not that I advocate using this method over the simple `\loop`; just another technique made possible by e-TeX extensions.

Answer (score 5):

@cmhughes: Your solution only required some modification, not deletion.

```
% Eg, \pdfappendix{MyPDF}{4}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\pdfappendix{\begingroup\def\x{}\@tempcnta\z@\dopdfappendix}
\newcommand*\dopdfappendix[2]{%
  \advance\@tempcnta\@ne
  \ifnum\@tempcnta>#2\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \edef\x{%
      \unexpanded\expandafter{\x}%
      \noexpand\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{#1\the\@tempcnta.pdf}%
    }%
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\expandafter\endgroup\x}{\dopdfappendix{#1}{#2}}%
}
\makeatother
```

With a dedicated counter we don't need an accretion of `\includegraphics`. Here is it:

```
\makeatletter
\newcount\mycount
\newcommand*\pdfappendix{\mycount\z@\dopdfappendix}
\newcommand*\dopdfappendix[2]{%
  \advance\mycount\@ne
  \ifnum\mycount>#2\relax
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \edef\x{\noexpand\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{#1\the\mycount.pdf}}%
    \expandafter\@iden
  \fi
  {\x\dopdfappendix{#1}{#2}}% 
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: +1 (when I re-charge my votes) thanks for posting, I'll study it as an exercise in expansion :)

Answer (score 0):

With [`functional`](https://ctan.org/pkg/functional) package, you can write this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{functional}

\newcommand{\pdfappendix}[2]{%
  \IntStepInline{1}{1}{#2}{%
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{pdf/#1##1.pdf}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\pdfappendix{MyPDF}{4}

\end{document}
```