# New table command with variable number of rows

Tags: macros, tabularx

I want to define a command to abstract a complexe table environment with vairable rows. Here is a simple demo:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{tabularx}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}\hline
name 1 & description 1\\
\hline
name 2 & description 2\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

According the answer of @egreg in this question: [New command with variable number of parameters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72902/new-command-with-variable-number-of-parameters)

I define a macros like that in the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/72915 :

```
\makeatletter %
\newcommand{\members}{
\tabularx{\textwidth}{|X|X|} \hline
\@stepone}
\newcommand\@stepone{\@ifnextchar\stopmembers{\@membersend}{\@steptwo}}
\newcommand\@steptwo[2]{
#1 & #2 \\ \hline
\@stepone}
\newcommand\@membersend[1]{
\endtabularx
}
\makeatother
```

I want to use it like:

```
\begin{document}
\members
  {name 1}{description 1}
  {name 2}{description 2}
\stopmembers
\end{document}
```

But, something wrong when compile:

```
Misplaced \crcr. \end{document}
Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{document}
Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{document}
Undefined control sequence. \end{document}
Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (\AtEndOfPackage): `c' used. \end{document}
Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{document}
Missing $ inserted. \end{document}
```

Someone can help me? Thanks avance!

Comment: A better solution might be to put your data in a `.csv` and then simply use something like `datatool` or `csvsimple`. You likely find such a solution easier in virtually every respect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use foreign markup such as `\members...\stopmembers`.

I'm also not sure why

```
{name 1}{description 1}
{name 2}{description 2}
```

would be easier than

```
\member{name 1}{description 1}
\member{name 2}{description 2}
```

Anyway, the problem is that `tabularx` is quite fragile.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,environ}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{members}{%
  \par\noindent
  \toks@={}%
  \expandafter\start@member\BODY\start@member
  \edef\BODY{\noexpand\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|}
  \noexpand\hline
  \the\toks@
  \noexpand\end{tabularx}}%
  \BODY
}

\newcommand\start@member{\@ifnextchar\start@member{\@gobble}{\@member}}
\newcommand{\@member}[2]{%
  \toks@=\expandafter{\the\toks@ #1 & #2 \\ \hline}%
  \start@member
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{members}
  {name 1}{description 1}
  {name 2}{description 2}
\end{members}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\makeatletter 
\newcommand{\members}{\def\@body{}\@stepone}
\newcommand\@stepone{\@ifnextchar\stopmembers{}{\@steptwo}}
\newcommand\@steptwo[2]%
   {\expandafter\def\expandafter\@body\expandafter{\@body#1 & #2 \\ \hline}%
    \@stepone
   }
\newcommand\stopmembers
   {\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|} \hline
    \@body
    \end{tabularx}%
   }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
\members
  {name 1}{description 1}
  {name 2}{description 2}
\stopmembers
\end{document}
```