# Loop for includegraphics

Tags: beamer, graphics, loops

I try to make multiple slides in beamer with 3 figures on each slide and the title.
I would like to loop through the list/array of figures and set the frame title.
The name of the figure files and the name of the frame should be different.

Here is the attempt:

```
\def\fnames{red, green, blue}

\foreach \name in \fnames {%

\begin{frame}{\name}
  \begin{columns}    
    \column{0.33\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=4.cm]{./plots/tot\name _log.eps} 
    \column{0.33\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=4.cm]{./plots/tot\name _log.eps} 
    \column{0.33\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=4.cm]{./plots/tot\name _log.eps} 
 \end{columns} 
\end{frame}%

}
```

The question: is it possible to set the title of the frame from a separate list or array. So instead of fnames, I would like to get it from:
`\def\tnames{white, gray, black}`

Comment: related (?) ["For loop" in newcommand](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20341)

Comment: Are you using `pgffor`? If so you may use the `/` for multiple lists (and variables). Otherwise you may consider to provide a MWE http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a PGF array and access it via `\pgfmathparse`, the array index starts from 0 instead. I've used `a,b,c` for convenience.

EDIT: Added a general content loop but still it is not that economic on verbosity.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,etoolbox}
\usepackage{mwe} %<- for dummy images

\begin{document}

\def\fnames{a,b,c}
\def\tnames{{"white","gray","black"}}


\foreach \x[count=\xcount from 0] in \fnames {%
\def\myframecontents{}
\foreach\y in{1,2,3}{
    \gappto\myframecontents{%
        \column{0.33\textwidth}%
        \includegraphics[width=4.cm]{example-image-\x}%
    }
}

\pgfmathparse{\tnames[\xcount]}
\begin{frame}{\pgfmathresult}
   \begin{columns}    
       \myframecontents
   \end{columns} 
\end{frame}%
}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Yuri: If you are happy with the answer, please upvote and accept it. That's the (nicest) way to say 'thanks' on TeX.SX.

Comment: Is it possible to make a loop inside the `columns` to repeat `\column{0.33\textwidth} \includegraphics[width=4.cm]{example-image-\x}` in a less verbose way?

Comment: I have been annoyed by the `<use image_file_name.pdf>` verbose too, while compiling beamer slides with an institute logo on each frame (where the logo was a pdf file). In `latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def`, you can find the definition of `\Ginclude@pdftex` which appears to be used to insert pdf images, and hardcoded in it is the verbose. I deleted the five lines following `\Gin@log` that seemed to be the problem and I can now compile my slides with less unwanted verbose. However, I do not have the knowledge to do that in a better way (in particular: persistent across updates of pdftex).

Comment: @ClickMe Sorry I forgot this apparently. Now added a loop, but it's not that of a shortcut.

Comment: Thank you very much for this introduction to arrays in tikz. Unfortunately, the above code seizes to work for me if I add `\usepackage[german]{babel}` to the preamble (whereas, e.g., english does not cause any problems). Do you happen to know why?

Comment: @anonymous Yes it is a known problem. Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117732/tikz-and-babel-error