# Compilation error: missing $ inserted

Tags: errors

I'm trying to compile this:

```
 %\chapterimage{m2summary.pdf}
 \chapter{Respostas e soluções}
 \begin{multicols}{2}
 \section*{\textcolor{ocre}{1. Matrizes}}
 \subsection*{Exercícios de fixação}
 \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
 \tiny{
 \item $\ds A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 & -2 \\ 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 2 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$
 }
 \end{enumerate}
 \end{multicols}
```

I'm gonna create a new document and use `\include{filename}` to include the code above. At my main .tex file, I use these packages:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}

\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{131,50,165}
\definecolor{yl}{RGB}{204,0,255}

% Font Settings
\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{pifont,bbding}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Bibliography
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,sorting=nyt,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,babel=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}

% Index
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

% Enumerate
%\usepackage{enumerate}

% Math
\usepackage{amsmath}

% Others
\usepackage{cancel,relsize}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl,subfigure}
\usepackage{stackrel}

% TikZ
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes,calc,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,through,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows,chains,positioning}
%\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathmorphing}

\tikzstyle{dot}=[circle,fill,scale=0.4]
\tikzstyle{dote}=[circle,fill,scale=0.2]
\tikzstyle{doto}=[circle,draw=black,fill=white,scale=0.4]
\tikzstyle{dotred}=[circle,fill=ocre,scale=0.4]
\tikzstyle{dotrede}=[circle,fill=ocre,scale=0.5]
\tikzstyle{dotredo}=[circle,draw=ocre,fill=white,scale=0.5]
\tikzstyle{dotreda}=[circle,draw=ocre,fill=white,scale=0.4]
\tikzstyle{pre}=[<-,shorten >=1pt,>=stealth',semithick]

\tikzset{
    node style sp/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=1cm},
    node style ge/.style={circle,minimum size=1cm},
    node style spe/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=.4cm},
    node style gee/.style={circle,minimum size=.4cm},
    arrow style mul/.style={draw,sloped,midway,fill=white},
    arrow style plus/.style={midway,sloped,fill=white},
}



% Letras \mathbb
\newcommand{\NN}{\mathbb N}
\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb R}
\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb Z}
\newcommand{\CC}{\mathbb C}
\newcommand{\QQ}{\mathbb Q}
\newcommand{\PP}{\mathbb P}

% Operadores
\newcommand{\mdc}{\operatorname{mdc}}
\newcommand{\mmc}{\operatorname{mmc}}
\newcommand{\sen}{\operatorname{sen}}
\newcommand{\cotg}{\operatorname{cotg}}
\newcommand{\tg}{\operatorname{tg}}
\newcommand{\cossec}{\operatorname{cossec}}
\newcommand{\dom}{\operatorname{D}}
\newcommand{\cdom}{\operatorname{CD}}
\newcommand{\ima}{\operatorname{Im}}
\newcommand{\idx}{\operatorname{id}}
\newcommand{\idm}{\operatorname{I}}
\newcommand{\suchthat}{\;\ifnum\currentgrouptype=16 \middle\fi|\;}
\renewcommand{\CancelColor}{\color{ocre}}

% Comandos
\newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}
\newcommand{\tf}{\therefore}
\newcommand{\raw}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\lfraw}{\Leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\lfaw}{\Leftarrow}

% Gráficos
\makeatletter
\let\pgfmath@function@exp\relax % undefine old exp function
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{exp}{1}{%
  \begingroup
    \pgfmath@xc=#1pt\relax
    \pgfmath@yc=#1pt\relax
    \ifdim\pgfmath@xc<-9pt
      \pgfmath@x=1sp\relax
    \else
      \ifdim\pgfmath@xc<0pt
        \pgfmath@xc=-\pgfmath@xc
      \fi
      \pgfmath@x=1pt\relax
      \pgfmath@xa=1pt\relax
      \pgfmath@xb=\pgfmath@x
      \pgfmathloop%
        \divide\pgfmath@xa by\pgfmathcounter
        \pgfmath@xa=\pgfmath@tonumber\pgfmath@xc\pgfmath@xa%
        \advance\pgfmath@x by\pgfmath@xa
      \ifdim\pgfmath@x=\pgfmath@xb
      \else
        \pgfmath@xb=\pgfmath@x
      \repeatpgfmathloop%
      \ifdim\pgfmath@yc<0pt
        \pgfmathreciprocal@{\pgfmath@tonumber\pgfmath@x}%
        \pgfmath@x=\pgfmathresult pt\relax
      \fi
    \fi
    \pgfmath@returnone\pgfmath@x%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

% Distributiva
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\newcommand{\DrawBox}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[->,shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt,out=70,in=130,distance=0.5cm,#1] (MarkA.north) to (MarkC.north);
    \draw[->,shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt,out=50,in=140,distance=0.3cm,#2] (MarkA.north) to (MarkB.north);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\tikzmarklog}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\newcommand{\DrawBoxlog}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[->,shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt,out=70,in=130,distance=0.5cm,#1] (MarkB.north) to (MarkC.north);
    \draw[->,shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt,out=50,in=140,distance=0.3cm,#2] (MarkA.south) to (MarkB.south);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

% Matrices
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}
\makeatother

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\input{structure} % Insert the commands.tex file which contains the majority of the structure behind the template

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\includepdf{capam2}
\phantom{a}{\thispagestyle{empty}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COPYRIGHT PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newpage
~\vfill
\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent Copyright \copyright\ 2013 X ao Cubo\\ % Copyright notice

\noindent \textsc{Publicado por X ao Cubo}\\ % Publisher

\noindent \textsc{XaoCubo.com}\\ % URL

%\noindent  % License information

%\noindent \textit{First printing, March 2013} % Printing/edition date

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TABLE OF CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{roman}

\chapterimage{m2c1head.pdf} % Table of contents heading image

\pagestyle{empty} % No headers

\tableofcontents % Print the table of contents itself

\cleardoublepage % Forces the first chapter to start on an odd page so it's on the right

\pagestyle{fancy} % Print headers again


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTERS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\include{filename}
\end{document}
```

The "best" part is: I'm creating some books (I'm a math teacher). This is the second one. The first one I compiled at college AND IT WORKS! --' So then I started to work at home, using WinEdt 8 and the latest version of MikTex, and it shows the follow error:

`Missing $` inserted. HOW? I tried to compile with no text, actually, with no math text, and it keeps showing that $ is missing. I really don't know what to do!

And what makes me "happy": compiling here, at home, the first book (that I wrote at college), it works! So I copy, paste the code, change what I have to change, but it stills show the same error message!

I'm so sorry for writing such a big question, but I don't know what really matters to help you to help me (lol), so I decided to write all the code here.

Thank you so much! :D

Comment: I think Your problem is related with `babel` package. Please look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117732/tikz-and-babel-error

Comment: But when I compile another file (with the same main file, just changing the "subfiles") that I made in the college, it works! By the way, how should I use the babel for portuguese-br? Thanks!

Comment: I think it is same character with `ngerman` babel, i.e `{"}`. Use same `\tikzset` environment described in the link above.

Comment: Adding all the code is not the best option, it's better with a *minimal* example showing the problem. That is, code starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, but containing only those packages and definitions, and the content necessary to reproduce the problem. Read more about creating such 'minimal working examples' at http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228 I can reduce your code to `\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\chapter{soluções}
\end{document}` and still get that error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code can be reduced to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
õ
\end{document}
```

and it will still throw the `! Missing $ inserted.` error. Exactly what happens 'behind the scenes' I don't know, but it may be that this is caused by your editor using a different character encoding than that specified for `inputenc`. According to http://www.winedt.com/installing.html, WinEdt 8 uses UTF-8 by default, but you've set `latin1` as input encoding. If I change `latin1` to `utf8` in the above code it compiles fine.

Indeed, `õ` in UTF-8 is the two byte character `0xC3 0xB5`; the first byte, in the one byte Latin-1 encoding corresponds to `\~A`, while the second one to `\mu` and this is the cause for the error.