# Brazil Language problem in the TikZ diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, babel, languages, tikz-cd

I have a problem with TikZ diagram, I don't get to make the diagram with `babel` under the `brazil` language.
I used the code with `french` and everything is OK!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, brazil]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[body={16.5cm,24cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{comment} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{defi}

\[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
Y_1 \ar[dr, "\pi_1"'] \ar[rr, "f"]& & \ar[ld, "\pi_2"] Y_2 \\
& X &
\end{tikzcd}\]

\end{defi}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is essentially the same as [Tikz and babel error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117732/tikz-and-babel-error)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, brazil]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzset{
  every picture/.prefix style={
    execute at begin picture=\shorthandoff{"}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
Y_1 \ar[dr, "\pi_1"'] \ar[rr, "f"]& & \ar[ld, "\pi_2"] Y_2 \\
& X &
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` doesn't seem to work with `tikz-cd`.

### Update

As of `tikz-cd` version 0.9c (released 2014/10/20), the `babel` library is supported and the following works.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, brazil]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}[2014/10/20] % ensure it's version 0.9c or later
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
Y_1 \ar[dr, "\pi_1"'] \ar[rr, "f"]& & \ar[ld, "\pi_2"] Y_2 \\
& X &
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

`portuges.ldf` (loaded by option `brazil`) makes `"` an active shorthand
that disturbs the `tikz-cd` code. The shorthand can be disabled via `\shorthandoff`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,brazil]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}   

\begin{document}

\shorthandoff{"}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
Y_1 \ar[dr, "\pi_1"'] \ar[rr, "f"]& & \ar[ld, "\pi_2"] Y_2 \\
& X &
\end{tikzcd}\]
\shorthandon{"}

\end{document}
```

(`\usetikzlibrary{babel}` didn't work for this example, `tikz-cd` seems to expect a `"` with catcode 12 (other), see `\tikzcd@enablequotes`.)

### Patch version

The following example patches some TikZ macros to support the active quotes:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,brazil]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\makeatletter
\shorthandon{"}
% Patch for tikzlibarycd.code.tex
\g@addto@macro\tikzcd@enablequotes{%
  \pgfkeys{%
    /handlers/first char syntax/\meaning"/.initial=\tikzcd@passquotes
  }%
}

% Patch for tikzlibraryquotes.code.tex
\def\active@tikz@quote@parser#1{\active@tikz@quote@@parser#1\pgf@stop}
\def\active@tikz@quote@@parser"#1"{%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar\bgroup{%
    \tikz@quote@@parser@group{#1}}{%
    \pgfutil@ifnextchar'{%
      \tikz@quote@@parser@apo{#1}}{%
      \tikz@quote@@parser@normal{#1}}}}

\g@addto@macro\tikz@enable@node@quotes{%
  \pgfkeyssetvalue{/handlers/first char syntax/\meaning"}%
                  {\active@tikz@quote@parser}%
}
\g@addto@macro\tikz@enable@edge@quotes{%
  \pgfkeyssetvalue{/handlers/first char syntax/\meaning"}%
                  {\active@tikz@quote@parser}%
}
\g@addto@macro\tikz@enable@pic@quotes{%
  \pgfkeyssetvalue{/handlers/first char syntax/\meaning"}%
                  {\active@tikz@quote@parser}%
}
\shorthandoff{"}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
Y_1 \ar[dr, "\pi_1"'] \ar[rr, "f"]& & \ar[ld, "\pi_2"] Y_2 \\
& X &
\end{tikzcd}\]

\end{document}
```