# Missing arrow labels in tikz-cd

Tags: diagrams, tikz-cd

I'm having some trouble trying to create the following diagram using [tikzcd.yichuanshen.de](https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/):
[image]

My document header is

```
\documentclass[12pt,openright,oneside,a4paper,english,brazil]{abntex2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
```

The site has generated the following code:

```
\begin{tikzcd}
n_1 \arrow[rr, "R"] \arrow[rd, "at"'] &                                                                              & n_2 \\
                                      & f_1 \arrow[ru, "at^{-1}"'] \arrow["S"', loop, distance=2em, in=305, out=235] &    
\end{tikzcd}
```

I'm getting this result with several error messages:

[image]

Any ideas on what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example produces an error. The problem is that `abntex2` loads `babel` with the brazil option, which changes the catcode of `"`. See this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198238/208544) for more info. Unlike in that problem though, loading the babel tikzlibrary does fix the issue.

```
\documentclass[12pt,openright,oneside,a4paper,english,brazil]{abntex2}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %% not needed
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel} %% added

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
n_1 \arrow[rr, "R"] \arrow[rd, "at"'] &                                                                              & n_2 \\
                                      & f_1 \arrow[ru, "at^{-1}"'] \arrow["S"', loop, distance=2em, in=305, out=235] &    
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Note that `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is not needed with up-to-date LaTeX.

Comment: Thank you! It works!

Comment: I apologize for returning to this question after already having accepted the answer, but is there any chance this solution wouldn't work inside footnotes? The usual problem with tikz-cd and footnotes seems to be related to the use of the ampersand but the suggested solution to this (using ampersand replacement=\&) does not appear to be working when I do it.

Comment: I'm not so sure commutative diagrams in footnotes is good style, but you can use the solution of the [linked answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198238/208544), i.e. setting `\shorthandoff{"}` before the footnote and `\shorthandon{"}` after.