# [spanish]{babel} and circuitikz

Tags: babel, circuitikz

When i use `\usepackage[british]{babel}` everything works fine, but when i do `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` everything brakes... I reduce the code and find out that the part with scope is the problem, but i can understand why.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,amsmath,graphicx,siunitx,pdfpages}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[americanvoltages,fulldiodes,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage[final]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,amssymb,commath}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[x=2.5cm,y=2.5cm]
\draw
  (0,0) to[battery1, l=$V$] (0,2) -- (2,2)
  to[R=$R_1$,*-*] (1,1)
  to[R=$R_3$, *-*] (2,0) -- (0,0);

\draw 
  (2,2) to[R=$R_2$, *-*] (3,1)
  to[R=$R_4$, *-*] (2,0);

\draw 
  (1,1) to[R=$R_5$, *-*] (3,1);

\begin{scope}[>=latex,color=magenta,thick,text=black]
 \draw[->,rounded corners=7pt]   
    (0.6,1.9) -- (1.6,1.9) -- 
    (0.7,1) node[anchor=east]{$I_a$} --
    (1.6,0.1) -- (0.5,0.1);

 \draw[->]
   (1.7,1.3)  arc(220:-50:0.4 and 0.15) 
  node[pos=0.5,above] {$I_b$};

 \draw[<-]
   (1.7,0.8) arc(-220:50:0.4 and 0.15) 
   node[midway,above] {$I_c$};
\end{scope}
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem probably is `>` which has problems with `babel`. Try adding `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` to your preamble.

Comment: Perhaps related/duplicate: [Tikz and babel error](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117732/5764)