# Custom Subsection Labeling

Tags: sectioning

I am currently using the command

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\alph{subsection}}
```

To have my document sections and subsections appear as:

1
1.a
1.b
2 ...

However, for my document's fourth section, I would like (combining subsections a b, and c):

**4

4.a b c

4.d**

How do I do this while keeping the other section labels unchanged? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want the subsections combined?  Why not just call it 4.a, and then move on to 4.b?

Comment: @Teepeemm Yes, this document is my solutions to a problem set in which parts 4a and 4b are coding problems and 4c is an analysis of those coding problems. I want my write-up to match the Professors problem set section labeling, but I don't want to leave 4a and 4b blank since it would look nicer and read easier as "4 a b c".

Comment: Just use `\subsection{\! b c}\addcounter{subsection}{2}`.

Comment: @Oni That does not work. The following section is still labeled "4.b" and the first section is now titled "4.a   (large space)  b c" since the argument entered in the subsection's braces is interpreted as the subsection's title.

Comment: `\begingroup
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.abc} 
\subsection{Subsection}
\endgroup
\addtocounter{subsection}{2}`

Comment: Oni's suggestion in the comment would have a subsection still labeled 4.b only because there's a typo.  But you should have spotted that in the error messages.  Try not to ignore compilation errors (that can be too easy in Overleaf).

Answer (score 1):

Like @Ivan commented:

```
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.a b c}
\subsection{Subsection}
\endgroup 
\addtocounter{subsection}{2}
```

Will add the `b` and `c` to the subsection and next subsection is `4.d`.

Answer (score 0):

To get something beyond what you want-- keeping in mind that such multiple-subsections may need to be clubbed later on-- let's take a more **general macro** for collating together as many subsections as one may choose... using the `\foreach` loop defined in the `pgffor` package, and nicely elucidated in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20342/146828).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgffor, amsmath}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\alph{subsection}}
\newcommand{\multisubsection}[2]{
                \subsection*{%
                   \thesection.%
                     \foreach \c in {1, ..., #1}%
                        {\addtocounter{subsection}{1}%
                         \alph{subsection}\,}\!. 
                             #2}}
\begin{document}

\section{The first section}
We have some questions answered in the following subsections.

\multisubsection{3}{A long answer, this should be}
When answering this question, we must consider the fact that
a complicated question expects a long and complicated, but clear answer.

\subsection{Answer to the second problem}
An easy answer, let's say.

\multisubsection{2}{Another, not-so-difficult problem}
Should have a moderately long answer, but as much to-the-point as possible.

\subsection{The next answer}
This should be evident from the above.

\end{document}
```

This should produce an output looking like this--
[image: Multiple-subsections]